# How to write typescript definition for is(constructor, instance) method

Tags: javascript, typescript, type-assertion

Let's say I have a `is` function, basically this is how it works.

```
is(Array, []) // true
is(String, '') // true
```

Coz it's a javascript function, i need to create a seperate typescript definition for it.

For now I can simply implement the interface below,

```
is(ctor: any, val: any): boolean;
```

But this definition is not good enough, coz after I run `if(is(Array, stuffA)) { ... }` the type of `stuffA` **cannot be inferred** by typescirpt compiler inside of the **if block**.

How can I make the **type assertion works** for the `is` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature should look like this:

```
function is<T>(type: { new(): T }, obj: any): obj is T
```

This will insure that the compiler understands the right type, that is this function is treated as [a type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

I have a function like that as well:

```
function is<T>(obj: any, type: { new(): T }): obj is T {
    if (Number.isNaN(type as any) && Number.isNaN(obj)) {
        return true;
    }

    let objType: string = typeof obj;
    let nameRegex: RegExp = /Arguments|Function|String|Number|Date|Array|Boolean|RegExp/;

    if (obj && objType === "object") {
        return obj instanceof type;
    }

    let typeName: RegExpMatchArray = type.toString().match(nameRegex);
    if (typeName) {
        return typeName[0].toLowerCase() === objType;
    }

    return false;
}
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20is%3CT%3E(obj%3A%20any%2C%20type%3A%20%7B%20new()%3A%20T%20%7D)%3A%20obj%20is%20T%20%7B%0A%09if%20(Number.isNaN(type%20as%20any)%20%26%26%20Number.isNaN(obj))%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20true%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09let%20objType%3A%20string%20%3D%20typeof%20obj%3B%0A%09let%20nameRegex%3A%20RegExp%20%3D%20%2FArguments%7CFunction%7CString%7CNumber%7CDate%7CArray%7CBoolean%7CRegExp%2F%3B%0A%0A%09if%20(obj%20%26%26%20objType%20%3D%3D%3D%20%22object%22)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20obj%20instanceof%20type%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09let%20typeName%3A%20RegExpMatchArray%20%3D%20type.toString().match(nameRegex)%3B%0A%09if%20(typeName)%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20typeName%5B0%5D.toLowerCase()%20%3D%3D%3D%20objType%3B%0A%09%7D%0A%0A%09return%20false%3B%0A%7D))

---

#### Edit

When using this function we'll always pass an instance and then the class.
As we want the function to cover all types we'll use generics, where `T` is the type of the passed instance.

If `T` is the type of the instance, then the type of the class is:

```
{ new(): T }
```

That's the "typescript way" of describing a contrcutor object (which is also a class).
More can be found here: [Difference between the static and instance sides of classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#difference-between-the-static-and-instance-sides-of-classes).

Comment: can you elaborate on this `{ new(): T }`?

Comment: thanks, pretty confusing topic, I'll try to understand it later

Comment: Thx. You save my day!

Comment: I think you can implment your is function in this way: `return obj != null && obj.constructor === type || obj instanceof type; `